# Storing/retrieving json data to mysql using jdbctemplate

Tags: mysql, json, jdbctemplate

I want to store/retrieve json object into mysql json column using jdbcTemplate. Here is my existing code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/template", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/html")
public String TemplateCreation(@RequestBody TemplateBojaClass dataFromUser){
    TemplateBojaClass objCreation = dataFromUser;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\objCreation.getTemplateName()+".json"), objCreation);

}
```

But I want to store the json data to table column instead of storing in folder file. I know that mysql 5.7 have **JSON dataType** So now I have created table like below,

```
CREATE TABLE `createTemplate` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `templateData` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I want to store the json input into that **templateData** column like below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/template", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "text/html")
public String TemplateCreation(@RequestBody TemplateBojaClass dataFromUser){
    TemplateBojaClass objCreation = dataFromUser;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     String sql="insert into template_creation(templateData) values(?);";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{**How to pass the json parameter here?**});

}
```

I could not found the solution from google. Somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this